# Amazon Virtual Private Cloud: running your own router instance possible?

Tags: networking, amazon-vpc

Read through the documentation and while there appears to be an option for running private subnets "behind" the public subnets with NAT and the built-in routing, I'd like to run, say, a three-legged pfSense router instance on the edge with a public-facing ("WAN") interface, a DMZ interface, and a private ("LAN") interface.

Can anyone confirm whether this can be done or not?

My primary reason for doing so is that I'd like to have control over the router (I'm a control freak) and secondly, I'd like to be able to setup my own IPSec tunnels because as far as I can tell, there's a limit of one (1) IPSec tunnel per Virtual Private Cloud and they charge an additional fee per VPN hour; I'd rather do my own and just incur any normal usage charges.

Comment: Bueller?  Bueller? Anyone? *crickets*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can because "EIPs cannot be used on instances in subnets configured to use a NAT instance to access the Internet. "

According to the [FAQ](https://serverfault.com/questions/269389/amazon-virtual-private-cloud-running-your-own-router-instance-possible)